# Vitest issue with vi.spyOn() when used with clearInterval

Tags: reactjs, testing, clearinterval, vitest, spyon

I've created a Countdown timer component and am writing out tests. I want to test that the `setInterval` gets cleared when the `distance` is less than 0.

I've set up a test as follows using `vi.spyOn(global, 'clearInterval')`:

```
test('should clear the interval when the distance is less than 0', () => {
        const date = setDate(SECOND);
        vi.spyOn(global, 'clearInterval');

        render(<CountdownClock endDate={date} etc.../>)

        act(() => {
            vi.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            vi.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            vi.clearAllMocks();
        });

        // expect assertions ...
    });
```

The code itself handles the timer inside of a useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        // Start straight away (ie before first second elapses in setInterval)
        if (distance() > 0) {
            runTimer();
        }

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (distance() < 0) {
                // Stop Timer
                endTimer();
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                runTimer();
            }
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);
```

The above test sets the date to 1 second in the future and then I run setInterval twice more using `vi.runOnlyPendingTimers()`. This pushes the distance into negative which stops the timer and clears the interval.

I've logged this out and I can see that the spy works in this part of the code - I can  see callCount of `1` after `clearInterval` has run.

The issue I get is that it then runs the useEffect return statement to clear up. At this point I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: clearInterval is not defined
 ❯ src/components/CountdownClock/CountdownClockContainer.tsx:94:12
     92| 
     93|         return () => {
     94|             clearInterval(interval);
       |            ^
     95|         };
```

I can't work out why `clearInterval` is `undefined` at this stage. My understanding is that `spyOn` doesn't create a mock and is rather 'spying' on the method so I can't figure out why `clearInterval` becomes `undefined`.

If anyone has any suggestions as to what might be the issue that would be great.

Comment: Does calling clearInterval trigger any UI change that you can detect? Do you really care that clearInterval is called or that something happen when it is called?

Comment: There is a UI change but not directly from calling clearInterval(), it's a state change in the same `if` block. But yeah, it's not testing a UI change. All this is testing really is that there isn't a memory leak that could happen if `clearInterval` doesn't get called.